# Bookshelf registry plugin and node cirrcular dependency errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I tried to use Bookshelf but got stuck with undefined models errors. So I tried to use the "registry" plugin as described in
[bookshelf registry wiki](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry).
I actualy got error mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/946). But there is just a reference to registry plugin and that node circular dependency managment issuesmay cause it. I tied to replicate almost exactly the example in the wiki.

My code:

db.js

```
var client = require("knex");
var knex = client({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'postgres',
        password: 'postgres',
        database: 'hapi-todo'
    },
    pool: {
        min: 2,
        max: 10
    },
    debug: true
});
var Bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);
Bookshelf.plugin('registry');
module.exports = Bookshelf;
```

user.js

```
var db = require("../models/db");
require("../todos/todo");
var User = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: "users",
    todos: function () {
        return this.hasMany('Todo', "user_id");
    }
});
module.exports = db.model("User", User);
```

todo.js

```
var db = require("../models/db");
require("../users/user");
var Todo = db.Model.extend({
    tableName: "todos",
    user: function () {
        return this.belongsTo('User');
    }
});
module.exports = db.model("Todo", Todo);
```

sample.js - works

```
var Todo = require("./todos/todo")

Todo.collection().fetch().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

this code runs as expected and produces the desired results.

sample.js

```
var Todo = require("./todos/todo")

Todo({
    description: "Walk the dogs",
    user_id: 1,
    completed: false
}).save()
.then(function(todo) {
    console.log(todo)
})
```

this results in:

```
/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/model.js:57
  this.attributes = Object.create(null);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'attributes' of undefined
    at ModelBase (/home/ubuntu/hapi-first/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/base/model.js:57:19)
    at Child (/home/ubuntu/hapi-first/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/extend.js:15:12)
    at Child (/home/ubuntu/hapi-first/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/extend.js:15:12)
    at Child (/home/ubuntu/hapi-first/node_modules/bookshelf/lib/extend.js:15:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/hapi-first/sample.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:933:3
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing somethig?
(I am fairly new to the node environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not related to the registry plugin. Anyway its use allow you to remove the `require()` to the related models on `user.js` and `todo.js`.

The fix is simply adding a `new` before `Todo`, because you can only `save()` an instance:

```
new Todo({
    description: "Walk the dogs",
    user_id: 1,
    completed: false
}).save().then(function(todo) {
    console.dir(todo)
})
```